# Can I know who up/down votes my answers/comments?

Tags: feature-request, votes

Can I know who up/down votes my answers/comments? If yes, how to check it? If no, could you make it possible?

Comment: I agree that all downvotes should be public.  Anonimity breeds vandalism and practially encourages retribution votes, and we've certainly seen that around here before.  Also, if you don't have enough conviction behind your judgement that something is wrong and are ready to defend your position, then I don't really want to hear your opinion.  Answers being peer-reviewed is a good thing, but who reviews the reviewers?  What if someone downvoted due to a misconception on their part?

Comment: @OlinLathrop Attitudes like that make me firmly in favor of anonymous voting. How bad would retribution votes be *if you knew who to downvote?*

Comment: @W5VO: Probably none at all.  Retribution voters rely on anonimity to vote for a wrong reason.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, to some extent I agree, but the reality is that nonanonymity of down votes will do little but encourage protracted arguments that get personal, and frankly, enable stalkers and whack jobs.  It will be rare, but once is too many times.

Comment: @Scott: Actually I doubt protracted arguments will happen any more than they do now.  And what about the retribution and vadalous downvotes that are happening now?  We can argue all day long what *might* happen, but without giving it a trial there is no way to know.  We've tried the existing system long enough, and it clearly has problems.  SE should do a small experiment to see what *really* happens when downvotes are public.  Try it on EE for the month of June, for example.

Comment: Why did this question received a downvote? Whoever who did it: can you explain why?

Comment: @AlejandroNava At really, this question received 6 downvotes and 7 upvotes. I just upvoted it (because I think it's an useful question indeed) and now it's even with 0 score. At 1,000 reputation points you can see the vote count, i.e., how many downvotes and how many upvotes. But who gave each vote, it seems that even the multi-thousand-users can't see.

Answer (score 7):

No. Voting on Stack Exchange in general is anonymous. That's just the way it is.

Some of us agree with this policy, while others think it should be changed. But it isn't likely to be changed any time soon.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that not even moderators have access to a list of voters.

Answer (score 2):

Even the community moderators can't see that. But it is registered in the database, and the CMs (community managers, SE employee) can. They register even the ips of the votes.

There are multiple watching/alarming mechanisms, used mainly against various misuses (like voting fraud using sock-puppets or so).